# Visifire Chart Reversed loop order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I'm running a foreach loop witch return results like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

however, i put these results as a datapoint in the foreach.
But on the page itself, the results get swapped.
They show up like this:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

The foreach loop looks like this:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (DetectorStatu status in loadOperation.Entities.OrderBy(d => d.Status))
{
    Detector selectedDetector = status.Detector as Detector;
    bool isAtlasFO = selectedDetector.EnabledDetectorTypes.Count(d => d.DetectorTypeID == 1) > 0;
    
    if (isAtlasFO)
    {
        DataPoint dataPoint1 = new DataPoint()
        {
            YValue = status.Status * 100.0,
            ToolTipText = GetTooltipText(status),
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
            Tag = status.Detector,
            AxisXLabel = status.DetectorID.ToString() + " ⚫"
        };

        DataPoint dataPoint2 = new DataPoint()
        {
            YValue = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(status.DateTime).TotalHours,
            ToolTipText = GetTooltipText(status),
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
            Tag = status.Detector,
            AxisXLabel = status.DetectorID.ToString() + " ⚫"
        };

        dataPoint1.MouseLeftButtonDown += DataPointClicked;
        dataPoint2.MouseLeftButtonDown += DataPointClicked;

        chart.Series[0].DataPoints.Add(dataPoint1);
        chart.Series[1].DataPoints.Add(dataPoint2);
        count++;
        if (count == 10)
        {
            break;
        }//Break loop when 25 is hit.
    }//End if Atlas FO
}//End Foreach loop
```

> **Now my question is:**

The foreach loop gets the results right as in the first example. However, the datapoints swap them as in the second example.

How do i stop this from happening?

With the current code (**Orderby**) it returns this:

[image: OrderbyAscending]

With **OrderbyDescending** it returns this:

[image: OrderByDescending]

Now what i want, is the orderByAscending. But the reversed. Because now it shows the best at the top instead of the bottom.

Also i can't take x (what i used to do) because right now, i'm using a if statement.

For example:

```
1
2 //
3 //
4 //
5
6
7 //
8
9 //
10
```

These are the first 10 results i take (if i ask for it). But the ones with // behind them are the ones that meet my if statement.

So in this case, i take 10 but only get 5.
This is also why i have a count in my foreach. It counts the results and when i hit 10, it breaks the loop.

Comment: what is Status? is that where you have the order detail?

Comment: Status goes from 0,01 to 1. So basically the ordered i showed in my question, but then with bigger numbers :)

Comment: foreach (DetectorStatu status in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(d => d.Status))
{....

can you try OrderByAscending?

Comment: When i do that, it shows me the results as in the example i gave. I want it to go from bad (top) to good (bottom) But instead, it goes from bad (bottom) to good (top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Status` holds the value, you are looping with the Descending order,

```
foreach (DetectorStatu status in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(d => d.Status))
```

try with OrderBy (which will sort in ascending order)

```
foreach (DetectorStatu status in loadOperation.Entities.OrderBy(d => d.Status))
```

EDIT:

you can get the Ordered 10 and reverse it,

```
 foreach (DetectorStatu status in loadOperation.Entities.OrderByDescending(d => d.Status).Where(d=> ((d as DetectorStatu).Detector as Detector).EnabledDetectorTypes.Count(d => d.DetectorTypeID == 1) > 0).Take(10).Reverse())
```

Comment: Made an edit in my question.  Also you see 2 total different images. This is because i only grab 10 results, while there are maybe 20+

Comment: When doing that, it gives me the same result as in the image shown. It goed from bad (Bottom) to good (top). 
What the problem is, is that the foreach gives the results in the right order. But what i think is happening is that the first result becomes a datapoint and get placed. Then the second result comes and also becomes a datapoint. But gets placed on top of the first one.

However i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @Mitch Can you store the DataPoints to SeparateCollection and finally reverse it, and then assign to Chart series?

Comment: and also see my Edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131132/discussion-between-wpfuser-and-mitch).